# Multicast Message queue

Tags: jms, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, message-queue, zeromq

I am sending out large streams of video to many machines on an internal network.
I would like to use a message queue, but I cannot afford to uni-cast copies of the video to each of the machines.

Is there any message queue that implements fan-out [send multiple copies of message to several machines] via multicast?

Since this is video, creating several unicast streams is out of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Video streaming via high level messaging technologies is probably a really bad idea in the first place. Why would you need messaging in the first place? What features do you need?

An IP multicast would disable most features of a messaging system since every message would be delivered at the same time.

Publish/subscribe is probably the closest you get to multicast on high level MOMs (RabbitMQ,ActiveMQ or other amqp/jms compliant suites). But I doubt it would be usable for video in most cases.

ZeroMQ is a low level messaging mechanism, closer to the wire - but without much of the high level features of MOM software. It supports multicast etc. Messaging systems using MQTT might be light weight enough to transport large amounts of video as well.

Comment: The features I want that I don't get from UDP: A) Garrunteed delivery & B) In order delivery. But I do want a UDP implementation to save bandwidth. Something like broadcast in UDP (best effort), retry in TCP (fix errors).

Comment: You are talking network microoptimizations - don't even bother go with a messaging product then. Guaranteed delivery is very complex - nothing even TCP can achieve. It actually requires the application to acknowledge that the message has been processed somehow. That done in correct order is very slow and requires a lot of network roundtrips however you design it. You can probably achieve some things using ZeroMQ as features building blocks for these situations, but I would still go with some standard protocol for video transmission. Like Nicholas answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about JMS for this, but you might want to look at Netty's RTSP protocol implementation.

Rtsp:http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt
Netty:http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/rtsp/package-summary.html